# Webpack dev server serves wasm with wrong mime type

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, webpack-dev-server, webassembly

I'm using Vue 2 (but I think that my question isn't Vue-specific). The application uses a WebAssembly library of mine that I've installed with `npm install [directory_name]`. When I run `npm run serve`, it serves the `.wasm` file as `text/html` instead of `application/wasm`.

I add this to `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    mimeTypes: { 'application/wasm': ['wasm'] },
  },
};
```

But in that case, I get this:

> Error: Attempt to change mapping for "wasm" extension from "application/wasm" to "application/wasm". Pass `force=true` to allow this, otherwise remove "wasm" from the list of extensions for "application/wasm".

Is it possible `cli-vue-service`/`webpack-dev-server` already knows about `.wasm` files, and I've understood something wrong about how we install libraries with `npm install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

It's tricky (assuming it's possible) to get webpack to load the `.wasm` file because of the way webpack works. What I did was add `-s "SINGLE_FILE=1"` to `emcc`'s options so that it does not produce a `.wasm` file; instead, it embeds the wasm in the glue `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Btw I came here after getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
```

I had a typo in my wasm fetch URL and I was fetching a file that didn't exist, but it was giving me this mime type error. Once I fixed the typo, everything worked. I didn't have to add the mime type to the webpack config. (maybe they fixed it since you posted in February.) I'm using the Vue development server.